# Probability of experiencing rain

Tags: probability

The question is:

You are going camping over the weekend, and there is $50\%$ chance of rain on Saturday and $60\%$ on Sunday (independent). What is the probability that you will not experience rain? Then, after giving your answer, assume they are not independent, and are positively correlated. Will the chance of having a 'dry' weekend increase or decrease?

The first part would be $0.5 \times 0.4 = 20\%$ that the weekend will not experience rain. Please help answer the second part. Thanks.

Let's say the correlation is 0.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A, B$ represent the events of rain on Saturday, and on Sunday, respectively

You wish to determine the relation between the probability of a dry weekend, $\mathsf P((A\cup B)^\complement)$, and the correlation coefficient $\rho$, where the latter is:

$$\begin{align}\rho & = \mathsf {Corr}(A,B) \\ & = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)}{\sqrt{(\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A)^2)(\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(B)^2)}} & = \frac{\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)-\mathsf P(A^\complement)\mathsf P(B^\complement)}{\sqrt{\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(A^\complement)\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(B^\complement)~}}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{100\mathsf P(A\cap B)-30}{\sqrt{6.0~}} & = \dfrac{100\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)-20}{\sqrt{6.0~}}
\end{align}$$

---

> Of course, we can get a qualitative assessment by observing that if $A$ is *positively* correlated with $B$, then $A^\complement$ is *negatively* correlated with $B$, $A$ is *negatively* correlated with $B^\complement$, and …  $A^\complement$ is *positively* correlated with $B^\complement$ .  
>
>  Thus, *if the marginal probabilities remain constant*, increasing the correlation of rainy days also increases the correlation of dry days.

---

$\newcommand{\Chi}{\raise{0.25ex}{\chi}}$ As to the derivation of the formula, remember that: $\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf E(\Chi_A)$ so $\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf E(\Chi_A\Chi_B)$.

Then:
$$\begin{align}\rho_{A,B} & =\mathsf {Corr} (\Chi_A, \Chi_B) \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf{Cov}(\Chi_A, \Chi_B)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(\Chi_A)~\mathsf{Var}(\Chi_B)~}}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf E(\Chi_A\Chi_B)-\mathsf E(\Chi_A)~\mathsf E(\Chi_B)}{\sqrt{(\mathsf E(\Chi_A^2)-\mathsf E(\Chi_A)^2)~(\mathsf E(\Chi_B^2)-\mathsf E(\Chi_B)^2)~}}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)}{\sqrt{\big(\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A)^2\big)~\big(\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(B)^2\big)~}}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)}{\sqrt{\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(A^\complement)~\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(B^\complement)~}}
\end{align}$$

Also $$\begin{align} & \qquad\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cup B)-\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B) \\[1ex] & = (1-\mathsf P(A^\complement))+(1-\mathsf P(B^\complement))-1+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)-(1-\mathsf P(A^\complement))~(1-\mathsf P(B^\complement)) \\[1ex] & = (1-\mathsf P(A^\complement))+(1-\mathsf P(B^\complement))-1+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)-(1-\mathsf P(A^\complement)-\mathsf P(B^\complement)+\mathsf P(A^\complement)~\mathsf P(B^\complement)) \\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)-\mathsf P(A^\complement)~\mathsf P(B^\complement)\end{align}$$

Comment: But what if the correlation is 1. So when Saturday rains that means that Sunday will also rain, how exactly does this increase the correlation of dry days. Also would you please explain your formula little bit, I don't quite understand the very first one.
I understand the correlation is the following formula, I don't understand where you obtained the one in your post. 
cor(X, Y) = cov(X, Y) / (std(X) * std(Y))

Comment: @szd116 The correlation cannot be $1$, for this question: that would require $A=B$.    However, observe that $A=B$ is equivalent to $A^\complement=B^\complement$, and so the more two events are positively correlated, then the more their complements are positively correlated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.